# in react-native with expo openning with android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

when i open react-native app
$npm start

> test@1.0.0 start
> expo start --dev-client

WARNING: expo-cli has not yet been tested against Node.js v17.6.0.
expo-cli supports following Node.js versions:

- > =12.13.0 <15.0.0 (Maintenance LTS)
- > =16.0.0 <17.0.0 (Active LTS)

Starting project at /home/pushparaj/Test
Developer tools running on http://localhost:19002
Starting Metro Bundler
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ ██▄▄ ▀ ██▄▄ ▄▀█▄█▀█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █
█ █   █ █▀▄  █▀ ▄▄▀▀▄█ ▄▀▀█ █   █ █
█ █▄▄▄█ █▄▀ █▄ ▀███▄▄▀▄▀▄██ █▄▄▄█ █
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▀▄█ █▄▀ █▄█ █ ▀ █▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█
█▄ ██▀▄▄▄▀▄ █▄ █▀▀▄▄▀▀▀ ▀▄▀█▀ ▄▀▀██
█▄▀▄▀ ▄▄ ▀▄▀ ▄█▀▄█▄ ███▄██▄▀▀█▄▀▄██
█▀ ▀▄▄▄▄▀   █▀█ ▀█▄▀ ▀█▀▀ █  ███  █
█▄██▀▄ ▄▄█ ▄█▀█  █▄▀██▄ █▄ ▀ ▀█▀▄▀█
█▄▄▄██▀▄▄▀█▀█▄▄█ ▄▄ ▀ ▀█▀█▄▀ ▄▀█ ▀█
██ ▀█▀ ▄ ▄ ▀▀▄▄▀▄█▄█▄ █▀ ▄██▀ █▀█▄█
█ ▀▄▀▄ ▄ ▀█▄▄ ▄█  ▄▄▀▄▀█ ▄▄█▄ ▀█ ██
█ ████▄▄▀▄ ▄█▀▄▀ ▀▄ ███ ██  ▀  ▀▄██
█▄▄█▄▄█▄█▀██ ▀▄█▀▄▄▀▀ █▀▄ ▄▄▄  ▀▄▀█
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █ ▄▀█ ██ ▀▄▀█▄▄▄  █▄█   ▄██
█ █   █ ██▄▄ ▀ ▀ ▄▄▄ ▄█ ▀  ▄▄ ▄█▄██
█ █▄▄▄█ █▀▀█▄ ▄▄▄█▄▄▄ █▄█████▄  █▄█
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▄▄██▄██▄▄▄▄██▄▄▄██▄█▄█▄██

› Metro waiting on https://expo-development-client/?url=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.43.94%3A8081
› Scan the QR code above with Expo Go (Android) or the Camera app (iOS)

› Press a │ open Android
› Press w │ open web

› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu
› Press d │ show developer tools
› shift+d │ toggle auto opening developer tools on startup (disabled)

› Press ? │ show all commands

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
› Opening on Android...

Error
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)